# Choosing a file in listbox Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox

I have a listbox of Matlab GUI that displays every files in a folder and a pushbutton. The program is supposed to run if I choose one of a file that displayed in the listbox and click the pushbutton.
Here is my code :

```
 allfiles = dir; %get files
 allname = {allfiles(~[allfiles.isdir]).name};
 set(handles.wavlist, 'String', allname);

 function wavlist_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     filenames = get(hObject, 'String');
     filechoice = get(hObject, 'Value');
     fileselected = wavnames{filechoice};

 function wavlist_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
         set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
     end

 function tab1button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     [y, fs, nbits, opts] = wavread(fileselected);
```

But I get error Undefined function or variable 'fileselected'. Any idea? Thank you...

Comment: please let us know, if the answer below was useful for you...

Answer (score 0):

In Function `tab1button_Callback` the variable `fileselected` is not declared.
You have to declare `fileselected` global or even much better put it into the  `handles` structure, which is an argument of all functions. This structure is intended to store user data.

```
allfiles = dir; %get files
allname = {allfiles(~[allfiles.isdir]).name};
set(handles.wavlist, 'String', allname);

function wavlist_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 filenames = get(hObject, 'String');
 filechoice = get(hObject, 'Value');
 handles.fileselected = wavnames{filechoice};

function wavlist_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
     set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
 end

function tab1button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 [y, fs, nbits, opts] = wavread(handles.fileselected);
```

Comment: Thank you Bushmills. But it still says Reference to non-existent field
'selected_file'. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Actually I want to process a WAV audio file. Does this happen because I don't include the .wav extension?

Comment: the variable `selected_file`does not exits in your code snippet. Can you please explain where you are using it? And you are right, if you don't include the file extension, MATLAB won't find the file.

Comment: My bad, I meant handles.fileselected not selected_file. But finally it's solved by adding guidata(hObject, handles); after handles.fileselected = wavnames{filechoice}; Thank you so much :)